# Finding a probability with z scores and a defined sample size

Tags: statistics

The mean starting salary of college grads is $\$45,800$. The population is skewed right with an SD of $\$9,100$.

What is the probability of $36$ randomly selected college grads having a mean starting salary less than $\$45,000$.

I know how to use a $z$ table. I'm just unsure of how to solve the problem when there is a given ($36$) sample size.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If
$$X_i\sim\mathrm{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
i.e. $X_i$ follows normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
then
$$\frac{\sum_{1\le i\le n}X_i}{n}=\overline{X_{n}}\sim\mathrm{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$$
i.e mean of a sample of independent $X$'s with size of $n$, $\overline{X_{n}}$, follows normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\displaystyle\frac{\sigma^2}{n}=\left(\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}\right)^2$

You can prove this easily by considering $E\left[\overline{X}\right]$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left[\overline{X}\right]$

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a new mathematician and I don't know what that squiggly line means

Comment: @MurphJones I added the English. Is it better now?

Comment: Much...Thank you!